# Requirement of a formal proof

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

There exists a continuous function $f$ whose domain is $[2,5]$ and the range is $(3,4)$. We have to prove that there exists at least one point $p \in (2,5)$ such that $f(p)=p$.

Now this is easy to see intuitively. The values of $f$ increase more slowly than the values of $x$ do. In the beginning, $f(x)>x$, in the end, $f(x)<x$. So, there must be at least one point at which $f(x)=x$.

But how do I prove this rigourously, using some mathematical arguments?

Comment: Do you know about the intermediate value theorem? (Assuming $f$ is continuous)

Comment: Yes I do.. But I'm not able to frame the statements so as to use that theorem..

Comment: Unless you require additional properties for $f$, the conclusion need not hold. If $f$ should be continuous, its range cannot be the open interval $(3,4)$.

Comment: $f$ is continuous. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Since $3<f(2)<4$ and $3<f(5)<4$,
$$g(2)=f(2)-2>0$$
and
$$
g(5)=f(5)-5<0$$
By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $g(p)=0$ for some $p\in(2,5)$, i.e. $f(p)=p$.